# Async middleware in tornado

Tags: python, tornado, middleware

My target is to validate the access token before each websocket request initialize. To do that I need to make a call to my oauth server. So attempted to add a middleware which will check the access token. I found how to add middleware in this link https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/issues/49 which works fine. But the problem is when I am making the call to my oauth server I am doing it asynchronous and it seems like middleware can't be a async. Here is my sample code

```
app = Application()


async def middleware(request):
    userToken = request.headers.get('Authorization')
    active = await check_accesstoken(userToken)
    if not active:
      return error
    app(request)

async def check_accesstoken(userToken):
    http_client = httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
    post_data = {'token': userToken, 'scope': 'email phone'}
    api_endpoint = 'https://192.168.0.4:1445/oauth2/introspect'
    json_data = json.dumps(post_data)

    response = await http_client.fetch(api_endpoint,
                                       raise_error=False,
                                       method='POST',
                                       body=json_data
                                       # headers=headers
                                       )
    return response.body.active:


def main():    
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(middleware)
    http_server.listen(PORT, HOST) 
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Getting following error.

> RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'middleware' was never awaited
>   self.request_callback(self.request)

Questions

1. How to add a aync middleware?
2. Or should I make a synchronous call to oauth server?
3. Or is there any other place where I should check the access token?

Comment: `HTTPServer` class calls the middleware like a synchronous function. You'll have to create your own server class by inheriting from this and then call the middleware using `await`.  It may or may not work, I'm not sure yet.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand what you are saying but can't figure out how to do that. If I create a custom server then that can act like a middleware itself. right? Can't figure it out how to hook async method in a synchronous process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it's more trouble than it's worth to override `HTTPServer`.

A saner solution that comes to mind is that you can subclass `RequestHandler` and create a [`prepare()`](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.prepare) method on that subclass where you can check the access token.

Then create all your handlers from that subclass. Here's an example:

```
class BaseHandler(web.RequestHandler):
    async def prepare(self):
        active = await check_accesstoken(userToken)
        if not active:
            self.write("Error")
            self.finish()


class SomeHandler(BaseHandler):
    ...
```

---

And if you need to create a `prepare()` method on your handlers as well, just call the `BaseHandler`'s `prepare` using `super()`.

Comment: I've BaseHandler class which extend tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler. There are two method being called when a connect is establish init and on_message. init is synchronous so can't do a async call there and on_meesage is asynchronous and I called check_accesstoken and it works fine. Problem is in websocket on_message can be called many times after the connection is establish but I don't need to check access token every time. If I could check the access token in init method that would be great. Anyway I guess as there is no support async middleware so I have to live with it.

Comment: One another thing in your solution how the prepare will be called?

Comment: @Aftab In case of websockets, you should create an [`open()`](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/websocket.html#tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler.open) method on your base class. `prepare` is for `RequestHandler` and tornado automatically calls it.